# Cyanogenmod: Google Play Services keeps crashing after update

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-services, oneplus-one

a few weeks ago I updated the **Google Play services** of my Oneplus One (Android version `5.1.1`, Cyanogen OS version `12.1.1`). From an apk that I downloaded online. Since then it keeps crashing. Sometimes every few minutes but sometimes also multiple times per minute. I can still use the internet but my instant messaging apps seem to receive messages with a delay. Probably because the push service of GPS is not working properly.

The crashes especially occur when connecting to a wifi, using other apps that connect to internet and sometimes also when writing text messages (SMS)

I didn't set up a Google account and disabled almost all my Google apps except for **Google One Time Init**, **Google Play services**, **Google App** and **Google Services Framework**. (because disabling them caused some problems).

The Permissions for **Google Play services** switched off, especially the *Location* permission was denied very often (~ 62000 times). *Wake up*, *Keep awake* and *Auto start* are allowed.

My phone is not rooted.

Google Play Services versions:

previous version: `7.5.71 (1955121-438)`

current version:  `8.4.89 (2428711-270)`

I also tried version`8.4.89 (2428711-438)` from [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-google-play-services-t2795911) but could not it install due to Parsing error.

This is the error message that shows up in the crash report.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgmscore.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.<clinit>(SourceFile:53)
at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLContextImpl$TLSv12.<init>(SourceFile:152)
at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLContextImpl.getPreferred(SourceFile:55)
at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.a(SourceFile:272)
at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.a(SourceFile:292)
at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SourceFile:552)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:175)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:155)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at com.google.android.gms.checkin.k.a(SourceFile:366)
at com.google.android.gms.checkin.k.a(SourceFile:238)
at com.google.android.gms.checkin.g.a(SourceFile:711)
at com.google.android.gms.checkin.g.doInBackground(SourceFile:678)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? Before the update my phone worked fine. Did I install the wrong version of Google Play services? Or do I need to setup a Google account?

Comment: I don't know many places online with good apks. But this one is pretty well [http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/] and I trust their apks.

Comment: @Rexford, thanks for the tip! I just downloaded and installed Google Play services again and it seems that the crashes stopped :)

Comment: So from now on, you know where to download your apks @Onion (sorry, I don't have your letters on my keyboard, but nice username!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the good places to downloaded your APKs are from [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/) (run by Android Police).

It is important to download your APKs from trusted sources for safety. In your instance, the apk is probably faulty, and as a result, giving you the errors.

Comment: That solved the problem! The version I installed was the wrong one for my phone. Version `8.4.89 (2428711-248)` from APK Mirror is working for me, and I guess any other Oneplus One!